# "A2070: invalid instruction operands" error in assembly when trying to use faddp/fsubp instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x87

I need to write a program in MASM32 assembly to compute some expression as an assignment. However when I try to compile the code, I get `"error A2070: invalid instruction operands"` on lines with `faddp` and `fsubp` instructions.

My code is:

```
.686
.model flat, stdcall
.stack

.data
    A REAL4 7.1
    B REAL4 2.2 ; C
    D REAL4 4.6

    CONST1 REAL4 7.0
    CONST2 REAL4 39.0
    CONST3 REAL4 3.4
    CONST4 REAL4 8.5
    CONST5 REAL4 9.4
    CONST6 REAL4 3.8

    TOP REAL4 ?
    BOT REAL4 ?

    RES REAL4 ?

.code
main:
    finit

    ; TOP
    fld CONST1   ; (1)
    fmul B
    fcos

    fld CONST2   ; (2)
    fmul D
    fsub CONST3

    fld A        ; (3)
    fmul B

    faddp        ; (2) + (3) -> (2)  | <-------- ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    fsubp        ; (1) - (2) -> (1)  | <-------- ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    fstp TOP

    ; BOTTOM
    fld CONST4   ; (1)

    fld B        ; (2)
    fdiv CONST5

    fld CONST6   ; (3)
    fmul D

    faddp        ; (2) + (3) -> (2)  | <-------- ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    fsubp        ; (1) - (2) -> (1)  | <-------- ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    fstp BOT

    ; RESULT
    fld  TOP
    fdiv BOT
    fstp RES

    int 3
    ret
end main
```

I compile it inside cmd.exe via `\masm32\bin\ml /c /Zd /Zi /coff lab06.asm`.

The output is:
[image: Compilation output]

I've seen a couple of examples of `faddp`/`fsubp` use on the internet and they don't seem to be taking any operands so I'm very confused about that.

I've also tried explicitly setting `ST(0)` and `ST(1)` as operands, but that resulted in a `error A2152: coprocessor register cannot be first operand`.

I'm not very experienced with assembly programming so I don't really know what could be going wrong. I would be really grateful if you could at least point me in the right direction. I'll gladly provide any relevant information about my system if that might be an issue.

Comment: Google says masm should accept `fadd` instead of `faddp`. Also, when you tried the operands, did you write `faddp st(1), st(0)` or `faddp st(1), st`?

Comment: In MASM versions (Prior to 8.0 I believe), `st(0)` is not understood by the assembler. In the earlier versions of MASM you have to use `st` instead of `st(0)` . You likely used `faddp st(1), st(0)` and got the A2152 error. Try using `faddp st(1), st` . On newer versions of MASM than you are using both should work. Alternatively `fadd` without operands will do the same thing as `faddp st(1), st` .

Comment: Using ``st`` instead of ``st(0)`` seems to have fixed my problem. I guess if I went with the ``fadd`` version I'd also have to pop the stack separately after that to achieve the same effect. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, if you use `fadd` without parameters it actually does the POP automatically. Using an operand(s) with `fadd` there is no POP. This peculiarity is mentioned in the Instruction Set Architectural manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fadd:faddp:fiadd _The no-operand version of the floating-point add instructions always results in the register stack being popped_

Comment: The same thing applies to `fsub` without parameter. Rreview the entire ISA here: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/

Comment: Oh, I see now. So ``fadd`` without parameters and ``faddp`` are basically equivalent?

Comment: `fadd` without parameters and `faddp st(1), st` are the same.